# how to make snippets auto complete in my custom vs code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

im korean beginner developer... help... T^T

i want to make auto complete like snippets in my custom vs code extension.

now my code,

```
const snippetBase = `axios.({
    url: "${service.url}",
    method: "${service.description}",
    `

const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
const selection: any = editor?.selection

editor?.edit(builder => {
    builder.replace(
        selection,
        snippetBase + snippetHeaders(snippetRes.data.header) + snippetBody(snippetRes.data.body)
    )
})
```

then, [my extension auto complete image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB4st.png)

I want to focus my cursor automatically inside the format after the snippet is shown.

Just like picture below.

[snippets image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oh5T.png)

help me plz!!

Comment: Do you just want to select part of the code you added?

Comment: Yes. I want my cursor focused at ${service.url} (in this example) after snippet has shown. after i press 'tab' the cursor should move to ${service.description}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds from your comment that you want the edit to act as a snippet.  Then you need to make a `SnippetString` and use the `editor.insertSnippet()` command which can take that `SnippetString` as an argument.  This should work for you:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
const selection = editor?.selection

const axiosSnippet = new vscode.SnippetString("axios.({\n")

axiosSnippet.appendText("\turl: \"")
axiosSnippet.appendPlaceholder(service.url)
axiosSnippet.appendText("\",\n")
axiosSnippet.appendText("\tmethod: \"")
axiosSnippet.appendPlaceholder(service.description)
axiosSnippet.appendText("\",\n")

editor.insertSnippet(axiosSnippet, selection)
```

`axiosSnippet.appendPlaceholder(service.url);` is the key to this, as  it will select that placeholder first and then allow you to `tab` to the next placeholder `axiosSnippet.appendPlaceholder(service.description)`.

[I don't know the structure of the rest of your snippet,e.g., `snippetHeaders(snippetRes.data.header)`.  If it is just text than you can use the `appendText` method with `\n` for newlines.